# Vscode shown Python 2.7.16... How can I change to 3.8?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I put on terminal VScode `python -V` it shows me:

```
Rafaels-MacBook-Air:PYTHON - PRESTON rafaelandrade$ python -V
Python 2.7.16
```

Answer (score 1):

Press on the end of left corner where `Python 3.8.0` in my case, and then change to your other installed Python versions.

[image]

Comment: You can read the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) for details on how the extension finds installed versions of Python.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of python is registered on the machine, open a .py file in vscode,
click on the python version at the bottom and then you can choose the environment you wish to use.

[image: Python version screenshot]